# how to change the radio button value like checkbox in angular 2 in *ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

**my checkbox :**

```
<input id="{{k.group_name}}_{{i}}" name="{{k.group_name}}" type="checkbox" class="hide" name="{{k.group_name}}" [value]="m.details" (change)="change($event, m , k.item_ingredient_group_key,false,k.maximum)">
```

**my radio :**

```
<input id="{{k.group_name}}_{{i}}" type="radio" class="hide" name="{{k.group_name}}" [value]="m.details" (change)="change($event, m , k.item_ingredient_group_key,true,k.maximum)">
```

in my json service i am getting the `is_selected = true` or `is_selected = false` based on the json value.

the `is_selected value` need to change as well.

I used the checkbox by binding it with `[(ngModel)]="is_selected"` it works fine for checkbox but when i change the checkbox the `[(ngModel)]="is_selected"` are changing as excepted but for radio button.

the true value and false value are not changing as like the ones in the check box checkbox

Answer (score 0):

First of all close your input tags:

```
//before
    <input id="{{k.group_name}}_{{i}}" name="{{k.group_name}}" type="checkbox" class="hide" name="{{k.group_name}}" [value]="m.details" (change)="change($event, m , k.item_ingredient_group_key,false,k.maximum)">

//after
<input id="{{k.group_name}}_{{i}}" name="{{k.group_name}}" type="checkbox" class="hide" name="{{k.group_name}}" [value]="m.details" (change)="change($event, m , k.item_ingredient_group_key,false,k.maximum)" />
```

Second, you have to name tags in your checkbox input:

```
//Two Name tags, what for?
    <input id="{{k.group_name}}_{{i}}" name="{{k.group_name}}" name="{{k.group_name}} "type="checkbox" class="hide" [value]="m.details" (change)="change($event, m , k.item_ingredient_group_key,false,k.maximum)">
```

Third:

Try to use checked for your radio button:

```
   <input id="{{k.group_name}}_{{i}}" type="radio" class="hide" name="{{k.group_name}}" [value]="m.details" [checked]="change($event, m , k.item_ingredient_group_key,true,k.maximum)" />
```

Comment: apart from this is there any solutions regrading my question asked ?

Comment: I have none at the moment, I will deep further and try to figure out later on :)